# split a file based on pre-defined set of rows

Tags: command-line, text-processing, split

I want to split a text file according to a pre-defined set of rows.
For example. I have a file

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

And then I have the following sets of rows (these could be stored however it is more convenient, on one file, multiple files,...).

```
1,2
3,6
5,4
```

I want to split my file so that I get 3 files back like:

file1

```
a
b
```

file2

```
c
f
```

file3

```
e
d
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `bash` script assuming your input file is named infile and the ranges are stored 1-per-line in a file named splits:

```bsh
i=1
for range in $(< splits); do
  sed -n "$(echo "$range" | cut -f1 -d, )p" infile > "file$i"
  sed -n "$(echo "$range" | cut -f2 -d, )p" infile >> "file$i"
  ((i++))
done
```

This simply uses `sed` to print the lines specified by the ranges, and saves each result as a new file (files created are named file1 file2 file3 etc). Two invocations of `sed` are used to preserve the specified order of the rows.

Note that there is no format or error checking done by this simple script, and existing files named e.g. file1 will be overwritten.

---

A simplified alternative (courtesy of [@muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru)) using `while read` and letting bash split the ranges instead of cut:

```bsh
i=1
while IFS=',' read n1 n2 
do
    sed -n "$n1 p; $n2 p" infile > "file$i"
    ((i++))
done < splits
```

If the order of the lines in the output files is important (e.g. rows 5,4 != 4,5), then the `sed` bit will need to be broken up into two separate invocations similar to the first script.

Answer (score 2):

The following python script will do the split:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('file', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
parser.add_argument('lines', type=argparse.FileType('r'))

args = parser.parse_args()

file_lines = list(args.file)

for i, l in enumerate(args.lines):
    r = l.rstrip().split(',')
    with open('file{}'.format(i+1), 'w') as f:
        for k in r:
            try:
                f.write(file_lines[int(k)-1])
            except IndexError: # Ignore lines out of range
                pass
```

Simply call it this way:

```
./split.py file lines
```

Where `<file>` is the abcdef file and `<lines>` the 1,2... lines range (you can even have multiple lines like 1,6,3,18,5)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it, in awk

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]=FNR; next;} {print $0 >> "outfile"a[FNR];}' index file
```

It reads the index file, and saves its line number (`FNR`) into an array that's indexed by the list of values on the line. Then it reads the input file, and uses *its* line number to look up what *output* file number to write each line to.

Answer (score 2):

Another simply [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) solution is :)

```bsh
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{ X[NR]=$0; next } {print X[$1] RS X[$2]>"out"FNR}' file lines
```

#### Explanation:

```bsh
NR==FNR    - Execute next block for 1st file only (*file*)
X[NR]=$0   - Create an associative array with key as 'NR' (line number) and copy
             whole line ($0) into it as its content.
next       - Jump to reading the next row from *file* (1st file)

print X[$1] RS X[$2]   
           - Print those line from array X that its line-number is the same as 
             value of first field in *lines* file then print a new-line(RS) and 
             print the line that its line-number is the same as value of second 
             field in *lines* file again and redirect the result into out#
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `bash` solution, assuming `input` as the input, `pattern` as the pattern and `output` as the output:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
i=0 # set the output number to 0
while read row; do # for each line in file `pattern` as $row
    columns=$(<<< $row tr ',' '\n') # store each line obtained by transforming ',' in '\n' inside $row in an array $columns
    for column in $columns; do # for each member in array $columns as $column
        sed -n "${column}p" input
    done > output$i # write column $column in `input` to `output$i`
    ((i++)) # increment the output number
done < pattern
```

Comment: @terdon Don't know how I could miss that, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The python script below will do the job as well:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#--- set the paths below
f1 = "/path/to/predifined_rows.txt"; f2 = "/path/to/outtakes.txt"; save_to = "directory/to/save/the/outtakes"
#---

rows = [l.strip() for l in open(f1).readlines()]
outtakes = [eval(l.strip()) for l in open(f2).readlines()]
for i in range(len(outtakes)):
    s = ("\n").join([rows[n-1] for n in outtakes[i]])
    with open(save_to+"/"+str(i+1), "wt") as out:
           out.write(s)
```

- Copy it into an empty file, save it as `outtake.py`
- In the headsection, set the path(s) to `f1`, `f2` and the directory to save the files to
- Run it with the command

  ```
  python3 /path/to/outtake.py
  ```

#### What it does

1. it reads the numbers from the second file, reading the lines as a *list* of numbers
2. for each of the rows, it collects the corresponding items of the first file (by index) and writes it out, to separately numbered files, in the directory defined in `save_to`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tool `split`. A bunch of examples can be found e.g. [here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/usplit.htm)

However, in your case something like

```
split -l 2 <inputfile>
```

will create a set of files with two lines called something like xaa, xab ...

Comment: Oh... I see my answer is wrong. AFAIK split cannot reorder your file.